# How do I manually route traffic from one network to another on the same routerr?

Tags: routing, vpn

I have a NetModule NB1600 acting as a router and a OpenVPN client. I have two networks (192.168.100.x and 172.16.2.x) on this router plus additionally the OpenVPN network (10.10.10.x) routes traffic to the 172.16.2.x

What I want to accomplish is that the 172.16.2.x has access to the public networks such as 8.8.8.8 How can I create this on the NB1600?

Comment: Can you post your config?

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

At bare minimum you would need to setup a NAT from your 172.16.x network outbound toward the internet.  There are a few ways to accomplish a route, but the easiest way would be to set a default route in the system's route table that points toward your internet default gateway.